# ORACLE: Identify and update invalid duplicate records

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, duplicates

I need some help.

I have a table as below.

```
+---------------+------------------+---------------+-------+
|    ITEM_NO    | ITEM_DESCRIPTION | ITEM_CATEGORY | ERROR |
+---------------+------------------+---------------+-------+
| TestItem10001 | TestItem10001    | Cat1          |       |
| TestItem10001 | TestItem10001    | Cat2          |       |
| TestItem10002 | TestItem10002    | Cat3          |       |
| TestItem10002 | TestItem10002    | Cat3          |       |
| TestItem10003 | TestItem10003    | Cat3          |       |
+---------------+------------------+---------------+-------+
```

**My requirement is:** Same `ITEM_NO` cannot have different `ITEM_CATEGORY`.
So in above table, `TestItem10001` has two different categories as `Cat1` and `Cat2`. Which is invalid. In such case, I want to update `ERROR` column with some error string like:

```
+---------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
|    ITEM_NO    | ITEM_DESCRIPTION | ITEM_CATEGORY |      ERROR       |
+---------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
| TestItem10001 | TestItem10001    | Cat1          |                  |
| TestItem10001 | TestItem10001    | Cat2          | INVALID CATEGORY |
| TestItem10002 | TestItem10002    | Cat3          |                  |
| TestItem10002 | TestItem10002    | Cat3          |                  |
| TestItem10003 | TestItem10003    | Cat3          |                  |
+---------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

Please suggest how this can be achieved in a cleaner way with less expensive approach as the real time table will have millions of records.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT1:**
Create and inserts as requested in comments.

```
CREATE TABLE STAGING_TABLE
(
    "ITEM_NO" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ITEM_DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ITEM_CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), 
    "ERROR" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)
);
Insert into STAGING_TABLE (ITEM_NO,ITEM_DESCRIPTION,ITEM_CATEGORY) values ('TestItem10001','TestItem10001','Cat1',null);
Insert into STAGING_TABLE (ITEM_NO,ITEM_DESCRIPTION,ITEM_CATEGORY) values ('TestItem10001','TestItem10001','Cat2',null);
Insert into STAGING_TABLE (ITEM_NO,ITEM_DESCRIPTION,ITEM_CATEGORY) values ('TestItem10002','TestItem10002','Cat3',null);
Insert into STAGING_TABLE (ITEM_NO,ITEM_DESCRIPTION,ITEM_CATEGORY) values ('TestItem10002','TestItem10002','Cat3',null);
Insert into STAGING_TABLE (ITEM_NO,ITEM_DESCRIPTION,ITEM_CATEGORY) values ('TestItem10003','TestItem10003','Cat3',null);
```

Comment: Please share create,insert statement for your data. and next thing, how to identify cat2 is invalid category? and why not cat1?

Comment: @MansiRaval - Added create and inserts in question description. And there is no logic to identify Cat2 as invalid. Cat1/Cat2 any one of the duplicates can be marked as invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it does not matter which row of the duplicates will be marked as invalid, you van use this query:

```
SELECT ITEM_NO, MIN(ITEM_CATEGORY) MIN_ITEM_CATEGORY
FROM STAGING_TABLE
GROUP BY ITEM_NO
```

which returns the minimum `ITEM_CATEGORY` for each `ITEM_NO` with a `MERGE INTO` statement:

```
MERGE INTO STAGING_TABLE s
USING (
  SELECT ITEM_NO, MIN(ITEM_CATEGORY) MIN_ITEM_CATEGORY
  FROM STAGING_TABLE
  GROUP BY ITEM_NO
) t
ON (t.ITEM_NO = s.ITEM_NO AND t.MIN_ITEM_CATEGORY <> s.ITEM_CATEGORY)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET s.ERROR = 'INVALID CATEGORY'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=96a9ba1f547b194bee2759db488985b8).
Results:

```
> ITEM_NO       | ITEM_DESCRIPTION | ITEM_CATEGORY | ERROR           
> :------------ | :--------------- | :------------ | :---------------
> TestItem10001 | TestItem10001    | Cat1          | null            
> TestItem10001 | TestItem10001    | Cat2          | INVALID CATEGORY
> TestItem10002 | TestItem10002    | Cat3          | null            
> TestItem10002 | TestItem10002    | Cat3          | null            
> TestItem10003 | TestItem10003    | Cat3          | null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below SQL to achieve your purpose

```
    select item_no,item_description,item_category,'INVALID CATEGORY' from (
    select count(item_no) over (partition by item_no order by item_category)item_cnt,
    count(item_no) over (partition by item_no,item_category order by item_no) 
    category_cnt,
    st.* from staging_table st)
    where item_cnt<> category_cnt
```